# Writing outside a header in tinymce with html5 schema

Tags: html, tinymce

I have changed my tinymce schema to HTML5. when i insert a `header` or any other HTML5 elements i'm not able to write something out of it.

not able to clicking outside, pressing enter or even using keyboard keys(up, down, ... etc).

the only way is opening `html` codes and putting my codes after or before manually that is not sanity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it myself,

have to set `end_container_on_empty_block` as true while initialing TinyMCE:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    end_container_on_empty_block: true
});
```

then double pressing the `Enter` will solves the problem.

**Edit**
Press home and then double pressing `Enter` will allow you to insert anything before.